# Как получить полный путь файла из Intent файлового менеджера?

Tags: java, android, файлы, android-intent

Пытаюсь получить полный путь файла, типа /sdcard/Download/file.txt
Написал код с использованием Intent

```
public void onClickSelectImage(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Uri path = data.getData();
        Log.d("Test",path);


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

На выходе получаю content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/documents.primary.....
Также пробовал `data.getData().getEncodedData();` и с использованием `File()`

Пишет снова не тот путь,что нужен.

Comment: Из интента в общем случае никак. Для начала надо понять нужен ли он вам на самом деле - для чего вам путь к файлу?

Comment: Вариантов много, от простого replace до манипуляций с курсором https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore